# Turn off the upper/right axis tick marks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make the ticks on the right and upper axis invisible and am not sure what the third line should be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(X,Y)
#plt.upper_right_axis_ticks_off()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As pointed by @imsc, You can tweak the visibility of the tick marks by setting the position of the ticks to the bottom and left (if you don't want them on top and right) using the  `ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position` and `ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position` methods.

If you also want to set the axis itself invisible, check out the [matplotlib.spines](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/spines_api.html?highlight=spines#matplotlib.spines) class. You just have to set the color of the spines to `none` using the `ax.spines[spine].set_color` method.

If you have a lot of plots to display, and don't want to turn manually the axis/ticks off each time, below is a function that will do the job for you.

Basically, you define for each axis the color you want (in this case `none` will render it invisible), and the function will also "turn off" the ticks marks for all the axis invisible. I have also added options to define the `linewidth` of the axis lines, as well as the `fontsize` of the ticklabels and the `pad` between the ticklabels and the ticks.

```
def customaxis(ax, c_left='k', c_bottom='k', c_right='none', c_top='none',
               lw=3, size=12, pad=8):

    for c_spine, spine in zip([c_left, c_bottom, c_right, c_top],
                              ['left', 'bottom', 'right', 'top']):
        if c_spine != 'none':
            ax.spines[spine].set_color(c_spine)
            ax.spines[spine].set_linewidth(lw)
        else:
            ax.spines[spine].set_color('none')
    if (c_bottom == 'none') & (c_top == 'none'): # no bottom and no top
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    elif (c_bottom != 'none') & (c_top != 'none'): # bottom and top
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', direction='out', width=lw, length=7,
                      color=c_bottom, labelsize=size, pad=pad)
    elif (c_bottom != 'none') & (c_top == 'none'): # bottom but not top
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', direction='out', width=lw, length=7,
                       color=c_bottom, labelsize=size, pad=pad)
    elif (c_bottom == 'none') & (c_top != 'none'): # no bottom but top
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', direction='out', width=lw, length=7,
                       color=c_top, labelsize=size, pad=pad)
    if (c_left == 'none') & (c_right == 'none'): # no left and no right
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    elif (c_left != 'none') & (c_right != 'none'): # left and right
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', direction='out', width=lw, length=7,
                       color=c_left, labelsize=size, pad=pad)
    elif (c_left != 'none') & (c_right == 'none'): # left but not right
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', direction='out', width=lw, length=7,
                       color=c_left, labelsize=size, pad=pad)
    elif (c_left == 'none') & (c_right != 'none'): # no left but right
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', direction='out', width=lw, length=7,
                       color=c_right, labelsize=size, pad=pad)
```

Below is an example of how to use it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ([ax1, ax2], [ax3, ax4]) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]:
    ax.plot(np.random.randn(10), lw=2)

customaxis(ax1) #default: no right and top axis
customaxis(ax2, c_left='none', c_bottom='none', c_right='k', c_top='k')
customaxis(ax3, c_left='none', c_bottom='k', c_right='k', c_top='none')
customaxis(ax4, c_left='k', c_bottom='none', c_right='none', c_top='k')

plt.show()
```

[image: spines]

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html

```
import pylab as p
t = p.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
ax=p.subplot(111)
s = p.sin(2*p.pi*t)
ax.plot(t, s, color='r',linewidth=1.0)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
p.show()
```

Answer (score 9):

`tick_params` should do it.

I don't have matplotlib installed on my current computer, so I can't test it, but this should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot([0,1], [0,1])
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off', labelright='off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
plt.tick_params(top='off', right='off', which='both')
```

I used above code with 'on' instead of 'off' ,for displaying tick marks on top and right along with default 'bottom'and 'left', in matplotlib 2.0

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format your answer to make it easier to read, see the formatting help button on the right of the edit box when you edit your answer.